# Javascript/jQuery: input 'blur' prevents 'click' being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

**jsBin**:
http://jsbin.com/eyARuHI/2/edit?html,css,js,output

**Code**:

```
$('#in').on('blur', function(event) {
  alert('input: ' + event.type);
});
$('#button').on('click', function(event) {
  alert('button: ' + event.type);
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<input id='in' type='text'>
<div id='button'></div>
```

**Issue**:
If focus the input and then click on button - `click` will never be fired.

How to properly handle click event in such cases?

Comment: don't use alert() in debugging purpose, use console: http://jsbin.com/eyARuHI/6/edit  alert() is modal and doesn't fit great with events

Comment: Because `alert` will put a modal window over the viewport preventing you from actually clicking on the button. Dismiss the alert and you'll be able to click the button no problem

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @RGraham try following JS. You will be able see that button event get fired every time when you click on it.

```
$('#in').on('blur', function(event) {
  console.log('input: ' + event.type);
});
$('#button').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('button: ' + event.type);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need stop bubbling events. Try this

```
$('#button').on('click', function(event) {
  alert('button: ' + event.type);
  return false;
});


$('#in').on('blur', function(event) {
  alert('input: ' + event.type);
});
```